# how do I create a list of the current shortcuts in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts

How do I output a list of the current shortcuts in Visual Studio 2010? I know I could download the posters from Microsoft and I think JetBrains has something similar. The problem is, we have other add-ons that map shortcuts and some of the shortcuts are not working. Resetting the mappings doesn't seem to help. I need to figure out the command to shortcut mappings.

Update - I'm looking for a tool to read the settings in Visual Studio and tell me the current mappings.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice userfriendly overview.

http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/Visual-Studio_2010.html

I hope that i helped you alot.